# creating optimized swf from a swc

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I've created a swc library.  Opening this swc, I can extract the library.swf.

Placing library.swf on my server and using it as an RSL, everything works fine.

If I run [optimizer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_04.html) against the library.swf, the resultant library-optimized.swf does not work as an RSL.  I get

```
Flex Error #1001: Digest mismatch with RSL
...
Redeploy the matching RSL or relink your application with the matching library.
```

in the log.

Is there something I am missing about creating a working optimized rsl swf?  I've tried linking against every piece of metadata [I can find](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the documentation skips the step on using the digest tool.

See [FLEXDOCS-432](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FLEXDOCS-432) for full details.